# Getting below exception while creating key out of one field coming in "value" part of payload

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

SMT is not working with below configuration, any idea

```
"transforms": "createKey",
"transforms.createKey.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey",
"transforms.createKey.fields":"column_id",
getting below exception

Exception:    org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:178)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:104)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TransformationChain.apply(TransformationChain.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.sendRecords(WorkerSourceTask.java:292)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:228)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey.applyWithSchema(ValueToKey.java:85)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey.apply(ValueToKey.java:65)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TransformationChain.lambda$apply$0(TransformationChain.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:128)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:162)
```

**Added configuration in kafka-connect as well:** `key.converter.schemas.enable=true value.converter.schemas.enable=true`, to enable the schema needed by class ValueToKey

Comment: Please show the data in the value of the schema

Comment: schema is not coming in the kafka topic only payload is coming, I am using debezium connector as a source

Comment: @cricket_007, schema is not coming in the kafka topic only payload is coming, I am using debezium connector as a source

Comment: Where is `column_id` in the value?

Answer (score 0):

This might be late however for me the problem was case sensitive. My column name was ID and in configuration it was id. So below is configuration that worked for me

```
transforms=createKey
transforms.createKey.fields=ID
transforms.createKey.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey
```